# Съезжают элементы на разных устройствах

Tags: android

Решил сделать первое объемное приложение, по коду всё отлично, всё работает, а вот по макету Activity у меня возникают большие вопросы на которые я не могу найти ответы в интернете, поэтому и спрашиваю у вас.

Основная проблема в том, что элементы при запуске на разных мобильных устройств стоят неправильно как планировалось иногда вообще выходит всё из экрана (устройства на которых тестировал: Honor 7a pro (абсолютно все элементы расширяются до невероятных размеров и выходят за экран), huawei p smart 2019 (элементы стоят неправильно). Эмулятор на котором работаю - Pixel API 28, там всё хорошо. Многие элементы создавались в Figma и были перемещены в проект в виде вектора. Я понимаю то что, проблема в dp и пикселях устройств, но как другие разработчики делают все без ошибок и их приложения поддерживают большинство устройств. Подскажите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен. Код activity_main.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fon"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
        android:text="@string/priv"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_light"
        android:text="@string/fdsf"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color2"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_robot_svgrepo_com" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
        android:text="@string/azac2"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_rashod"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_values"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_rashod" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_values"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_group_2btn_values" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_currence"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_rashod"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_group_3btn_money" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_values"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_group_4btn_aboutapp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Приложение запущено на Huawei P Smart 2019]

[image: Эмулятор Pixel в Android Studio]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Слетают со своих мест элементы xml на других мобильных устройствах. Как это исправить можно, чтобы плюс минус подходило ко всем мобильным устройствам?

Comment: У тебя на TextView text1 и text2 стоит ширина wrap_content (да и почти на всех вьюхах)... Что бы сделать разметку относительной - используй вспомогательные линии (gudeline) их расположение можно задавать в процентах от параметров экрана. И по ним уже выравнивай остальные view. И с wrap_content для view стоит по аккуратней быть

Comment: Спасибо большое. Добавил Gudeline в режиме Design по вертикали и горизонтали в процентах и поместил внутрь их элементы, всё стало работать.